# Blurry UI when using Screen Space Camera

Tags: unity, gui

I am using Screen-Space Camera as a render mode on canvas but the Textmeshpro text and other UI elements are looking blurry around edges. I think it might be due to canvas scaler setting. After changing plane distance or making canvas child of camera problem still exist.Following is the result I am getting in unity and Canvas settings. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After playing with different settings finally, I solved it after disabling Allow HDR on camera setting.